# Why do I not see a :before border when using flexboxes

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the [following CSS](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJiFES5mZVCw2Sh4YtPS)...

```
.border:before{
    content: "";
    color:black;
    border-left:10px solid black;
    height:90%;

}
.border{
  display:flex;
}
```

If I remove the display flex I see the border, however, when I add the display flex it disappears. Basically looking to have a side border that is only 90% the height of the div.

Comment: yeah using the info provided I will look through my plnkrs and see if I can find the final solution.

Comment: Hi Jackie, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Take a look in the comments I think the plunkers there are what I did

Comment: The ones that I posted via comments?

Comment: Yeah sorry missed that

Answer (score 2):

## Problem:

The reason is that you don't have a `height` specified on `.border`. The `::before` pseudo-element has a `height` declared in `%`. Since `.border` doesn't have a specific `height`, then the `height` of the pseudo-element is set to `0`.

---

## Solution:

Specify a `height` on `.border`, or on the pseudo-element.

```css
/* Styles go here */
.border:before{
    content: "";
    color:black;
    border-left:10px solid black;
    height:90%;
    
}
.border{
  display:flex;
  height:42px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="border">Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

---

## Alternative Solution

Alternatively, you could just add the border to `.border` itself and not use a pseudo-element.

```css
/* Styles go here */
.border{
  display:flex;
  border-left:10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="border">Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It is interesting that adding an explicit height on border works. However, this is embedded in a bunch of other flex boxes and height needs to be managed so explicit height won't work for me. As for the second one, is the border only taking up 90% of the height? That is important as well. Could you post the raw plnkr urls so I can play?

Comment: Here is the first version, as a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0LSFPgztahVWywPpb7oQ, and the second: http://plnkr.co/edit/DzZdlTtvjwKci3HtQw0k?p=info

Comment: Try clearing your cache. When I check both those links, they are both updated correctly. I've tested again on my computer, along with a second computer and a smartphone.